# Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

Unlike in English, in German there are quite a few words that contain a hyphen, e.g., "Arbeiter-Unfallversicherung" (workers' accident insurance). By default, (La)TeX will only break such words after the existing hyphen and disregard all other breakpoints. This behaviour will often result in overfull hboxes for German texts.

There are at least three ways to achieve proper hyphenation, two of which use shorthands of the `babel` package and none of which I consider to be really satisfactory:

1. The `"=` shorthand: `Arbeiter"=Unfallversicherung`. This allows every (otherwise legal) breakpoint and therefore may produce correct but unfavourable hyphenation (e.g. Arbeiter-Un-fallversicherung). This seems to be a method of last resort, suited for documents to be created with (almost) no manual intervention.
2. The `\-` command: `Ar\-beiter-Unfall\-ver\-si\-che\-rung`. By manually setting allowed breakpoints, one can avoid unfavourable ones shortly before or after a present hyphen (I use a minimum of four characters as a rule of thumb). As a downside, one has to look up the correct breakpoints of the respective words. Also, the body of a LaTeX document may become quite cluttered.
3. The `"-` shorthand: `Ar"-beiter-Unfall"-versicherung`. This method (the one I'm currently using) also avoids unfavourable breakpoints and allows for a tidier document body. But one still has to look up the correct breakpoints.

To cut a long story short: Is there a way to automatically allow hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen, while *disregarding breakpoints less than, say, four characters before or after the existing hyphen?*

Comment: Just a side note (I have no solution for the real problem): I would find “Arbeiterunfallversicherung” more natural looking in German. Duden even has the entry “Arbeiterunfallsversicherungsgesetz”, though in the section on adding hyphens it does concede that one could add a hyphen there. (The ÖWB doesn’t have a corresponding entry.)

Comment: Sometimes the hyphen in German words is sort of optional, sometimes it's mandatory, e.g. in "öffentlich-rechtlich" (public-law).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. You could possibly use an external parsing script to apply one of those options to a text, but writing that would still be a lot of work, so manually adding commands is probably less work in practice.

Future update: LuaTeX has rudimentary support for some special hyphenation cases, and in a future version (spring 2014, most likely) there will be core support for weighted hyphenation and multiple hyphenation passes.

Comment: Are there now some news about the special hyphenation in LuaTex?

Comment: What is the situation in 2018? Any news?

Comment: I'm just a beginner in using LuaTeX, but [here's an example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417746/allow-latex-to-hyphenate-words-with-dashes/417883#417883) of allowing hyphenation within words already containing a hyphen. One could extend that with a pre- or post- pass that does more tweaking, e.g. not allow hyphenation “near” the hyphen, etc.

Answer (score 46):

This seems to be what the [hyphenat](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyphenat/) package is for.  From the manual:

> TeX does not want to hyphenate a word that appears in the source
>    already hyphenated, such as `electromagnetic-endioscopy`.
>       The `\hyp` command is like the other `\...hyp` commands, only it
>    typesets a hyphen and allows full automatic hyphenation of the other
>    words forming the compound word. It is used like
>    `electromagnetic\hyp{}endioscopy`.

I'm not sure about your last criterion, though it seems that if TeX applies its normal hyphenating rules then this would be unlikely to happen anyway since (I think) that what happens is that the word after the `\hyp{}` is treated (as far as hyphenation is concerned) as a new word and I guess that not many words get hyphenated in the first (or last) few characters.

Comment: It sounds like this does the same as babel's `"=` shorthand?

Comment: The effect of the `\hyp{}` command seems to be similar to that of the `"=` babel shorthand. As far as I understand, the text before and the one after these commands are treated as separate words. Unfortunately (regarding to my question), words that may be hyphenated with only two characters separated from the rest are quite common in German.

Comment: @lockstep: I wondered about that, but figured that if you knew about hyphenat then you'd've explained why it didn't work so thought it worth at least mentioning.

Comment: Only `electromagnetic\BreakableHyphen{}endioscopy` works for me (KOMA-script book, babel frenchle, LyX). Of course, as I am under LyX, `\BreakableHyphen{}` is in a TeX box.

Comment: @TacoHoekwater The solution of \hyp{} is much more broad, for example it works with Polyglossia under XeLaTeX while the "= shorthand does not!

Comment: I can't use the babel shorthand because I'm using polyglossia for English. The `\hyp{}` works well.  It looks better combined with `newunicodechar`: `\usepackage{newunicodechar}`, then `\newunicodechar{‐}{\hyp{}}`.  That's an Unicode hyphen, u+2010. Now you can write Tex text like e.g. `pitch‐accentual` (again, that's a Unicode hyphen) and Tex will be able to further hyphenate them if needed.

Answer (score 27):

With LuaTeX, a simple solution is to enter explicit hyphens in the `\hyphenation` command as `=`.

```
\hyphenation{Ar-beiter=Unfall-ver-si-che-rung}
\showhyphens{Arbeiter-Unfallversicherung}
\bye
```

After compiling this document with LuaTeX, the .log file shows that hyphenation is possible

```
[][] \tenrm Ar-beiter-Unfall-ver-si-che-rung
```

with hyphenations *Arbei-ter...* and *...Un-fallversicherung* omitted as requested by the `\hyphenation` command.

That way, no further mark-up is required in the document source for LuaTeX to handle (a selection of) words automatically.  It's not a fully automatic solution, though, since an explicit list of words needs to be maintained.  And all hyphens are hard-coded, *i.e.*, changing inner word hyphen minima is tedious.  Still room for improvements ...

[The LuaTeX manual](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatexref-t.pdf) has some more information on hyphenation related differences to Knuth's TeX in section “Languages and characters, fonts and glyphs”.

Comment: Any updates on this? Can LuaTeX be made to do this automatically yet?

Comment: @gaussler - Please see the answer I've provided to the query [Enable extra hyphenation points for compound words that already contain a hyphen character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298793/5001) The solution combines a Lua function and the "magic" of the `babel` `"=` shorthand. :-)

Comment: Is there a related command in xelatex? Using `=` causes it to complain.

Answer (score 17):

You can set `\lefthyphenmin=4` to ensure at least 4 characters after the explicit `"=` hyphen before any hyphens inserted by tex. (It really sets that there should be 4 characters after the beginning of *any word*, not only compound words with a `"=`.)

It's possible to make the change to `\lefthyphenmin` locally, but it is awkward. Tex only looks at the value of `\lefthyphenmin` at the beginning of paragraphs and at language changes, so you have to write  something like: `{\lefthyphenmin4\setlanguage\language ...}\setlanguage\language`

Answer (score 4):

See [egreg’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63234/) to question [Why can words with hyphen char not be hyphenated?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63232/)

> Indeed, if you try the following example, you'll see that TeX hyphenates the compound word:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
> \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
> \begin{document}
> \hyphenchar\font=\string"7F
>
> \parbox{1pt}{In Baden-W\"urttemberg}
>
> \end{document}
> ```

Answer (score -5):

A simple solution is to use the -- character instead of a hyphen. This produces a wide hyphen (m-bar) and does not prevent the hyphenation of any of the joined words. An advantage of this approach is that it becomes graphically clear where the original hyphen was and where a hyphen was inserted. Of course, you only want to use this approach in words that need to be hyphenated.

Comment: Sorry, but using `--` *does* prevent hyphenation in the joined words.

Comment: Besides @egreg's remark: this is typographically unacceptable.

Comment: @egreg, I use XeLaTex and it works fine.

Comment: @clemens, I beg to disagree, this is typographically much better than having two identical hyphens in a composite word.

Comment: @Ariel I know that typography is not a science so there is no absolute truth but I'm still curious: do you know of any typographer who supports your claim? Any typographic book which has the same advice?

Comment: @clemens, truly, I don't consult typographic manuals... Anyhow, I saw it as a quick and neat solution (at least in XeLatex where it works). You may call it a quick and dirty solution, if you wish.