# Hyphenation of words with exotic characters

Tags: hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/adequate-hyphenation-of-words-already-containing-a-hyphen)

As a mathematician, I often have to write documents with long words containing embedded mathematical symbols, e.g. λ-representation, -homomorphism, κ-accessible, etc. Neither XeTeX nor LuaTeX is able to correctly hyphenate those words, regardless of whether I'm using `unicode-math` or `mathspec` or directly inputting Unicode characters. Is there a package or an option I can use to automatically hyphenate these words, without having to insert discretionary hyphens by hand everywhere?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
(ii). Clearly, the constant functions and projection functions admit λ-representations, and the composition of λ-representable functions is certainly λ-representable. The conclusion follows from (i).

(ii). Clearly, the constant functions and projection functions admit $\lambda$-representations, and the composition of $\lambda$-representable functions is certainly $\lambda$-representable. The conclusion follows from (i).
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not so much the exotic characters as the `-` TeX doesn't hyphenate explicitly hyphenated words. have a look at `\hyph` from `hyphenat` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/adequate-hyphenation-of-words-already-containing-a-hyphen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it’s a general “problem” with words containing a dash. TeX prevents to hyphenate words like this. With `babel` one can use `"=` to insert a dash not disturbing other hyphenation points. As David says you may have a look at [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/adequate-hyphenation-of-words-already-containing-a-hyphen).