# Hyphenation problem

Tags: hyphenation

I am having trouble with the hyphenation of a project I am writing. More precisely it will not hyphenate the word $\ast$-homomorphism. I have tried with `\hyphenation{ho-mo-mor-phism}`, but to no luck. Of course I suspect that it is the `$\ast$-` which courses the problem, but why? and how do I make the word hyphenate?

Here is an example where my problem occurs:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,draft]{article}

\hyphenation{ho-mo-mor-phism}

\begin{document}

I would really much like to have the---frequently
appearing---word $\ast$-homomorphism hyphenated.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package [hypenat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypenat) is designed to allow for this sort of thing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

I would really much like to have the---frequently
appearing---word $\ast$\hyp{}homomorphism hyphenated.

\end{document}
```

It makes the the point after the dash breakable, whence the following word can be hyphenated.

[image: hyphenation of homomorphism]

(The hyphenation point is slightly different as I actually used the `standalone` class to produce this image and it did it with a different line width.)

Comment: Actually between `$\ast$` and `homomorphism` is the only place I don't want the word hyphenated. How do I make hyphenation possible in `homomorphism` but tell LaTeX that it should not hyphenate after `$\ast$`? Is there no solution such as `\hyphenate{...}`, so that you specify where hyphenation is to take place and avoid replacing `-` with `\hyp{}` in all occurrences of `$\ast$-homomorphism`, becuase I already have quite a few pages.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear from your question.  In that case, I have bad news for you: take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706/86  Indeed, based on that comment I'd say this question is (unfortunately - given the answer there) a duplicate of that one.

Comment: No, this was not one of my questions. Your answer just made me ralize that it was a problem I had not thought of. The real question was how to make LaTeX hyphenate the word `$\ast$-homomorphism`. I'm just sorry that I have to search and replace all the files in my document. But I guess that's  life. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using a "local hyphenation" technique:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,draft]{article}

\begin{document}

I would really much like to have the---frequently
appearing---word $\ast$-ho\-mo\-mor\-phism hyphenated.

\end{document}​
```