# Add hyphenation-rule for hyphenated words

Tags: hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/adequate-hyphenation-of-words-already-containing-a-hyphen)

Is there any way to define permissible hyphenations for hyphenated words?

For example, even if I have hyphenations defined for the words *semi* and *computable*, LaTex still fails to break the word *semi-computable*. And if I add to the preamble

```
\hyphenation{se-mi-com-p-ut-a-ble}
```

that will only add a rule for *semicomputable*, not *semi-computable*.

EDIT: commentor had the answer [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/adequate-hyphenation-of-words-already-containing-a-hyphen)

Basically, writing *semi"=computable* should do the trick
.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).