# How to change hyphenation of a particular word

Tags: hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94344/add-hyphenation-rule-for-hyphenated-words?rq=1)

How to change hyphenation of a particular word?

specifically I don't like how it is line breaking position

```
       ...po-
 sition...
```

I would like to have it

```
     ...pos-
ition...
```

is there a way to change this?

PS You may or may not agree with the hyphenation of position

Comment: @ dodohjk Use \hyphenation{pos-ition}

Comment: looks like my question was much easier to answer than I thought

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put

```
\hyphenation{pos-ition}
```

In the preamble.

You can find more info on the [Wikibooks LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Hyphenation)

Answer (score 5):

One idea is to use

`pos\-ition`

In general you can locally hyphenate a word using `\-` wherever you want the word to split. For expample

`und\-er\-sta\-nd`

Comment: this is a solution to my problem but it does not answer the question. Could be useful if I didn't want to change the hyphenation of position for the all document

Comment: @dodohjk: That's why I said `localy`! I didn't know that you wanted it for all the text!