# Global setting of hyphenation for words containing dashes

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

I'm using the word "Zwei-Drittel-Abstimmungsmehrheit" a bunch of times in my document. Often it won't fit into the current line, extending into the right margin.

I figured out that the following package helps :

```
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
```

Then I can write

```
Zwei\-/-Drittel\-/Abstimmungs\-mehrheit
```

and the hyphenation is done correctly.

Is there a way that I can set this hyphenation globally for this word? Like i can do it with the command

```
\hyphenation{...}
```

Sadly this command doesn't work for words containing dashes.

Comment: Why not simply `\def\Zwei{Zwei\-/-Drittel\-/Abs\-tim\-mungs\-mehr\-heit}` in the preamble and `\Zwei` in text?. On the other hand, the `microtype` package is a must using worm-like words.

Comment: That is what I'm currently using but if there are many words it could be difficult to remember all the commands and it is bad because I'm not the only Person who writes the document

Answer (score 4):

In the question [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/adequate-hyphenation-of-words-already-containing-a-hyphen), I was looking for a fully automatic solution (i.e., without special shorthands in the document body *and* without using `\hyphenation` or similar commands) to disregard break points less than four characters before and after existing hyphens. From Stephan Henning's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162957/510) I learned that at least a solution with `\hyphenation` is available *if you're willing to switch to Lua(La)TeX*. Compile the following example with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\hyphenation{Zwei=Drittel=Abstimmungs-mehr-heit}

\textwidth=120pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

Zwei-Drittel-Abstimmungsmehrheit

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Switching to LuaTeX is now not an option for me.