# Force hyphenation for a word beginning with a digit

Tags: hyphenation

What is the best way to make LaTeX hyphenate the word `9-dimensional`. Currently I have a case where it produces an overfull line without hyphenation. Adding `\hyphenation{9-di-men-sional}` doesn't work because it contains a digit. Using `9- dimensional` looks ugly because of the white space.

Comment: I would say that this is a duplicate to [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706)

Comment: @Johannes_B -- not quite the same.  that question/answer doesn't deal with anything that isn't a letter.  (i've added an answer that shows what we do for tugboat.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The `hyphenat`-solution works just fine. Isn't the reason for not breaking the same? Or is the behaviour really different with a number?

Comment: @Johannes_B -- actually, under most circumstances, i would say that this shouldn't be broken.  but there are times, ...  what usually happens when this technique is applied is that the number itself isn't broken off, but hyphenation becomes "permissible" somewhere in the following word.  if it's a long word, and the break after the `9-` leaves extreme spaces in the broken line, hyphenating the word is more attractive.  i don't dispute that `hyphenat` works, just that it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

replace the hyphen with a macro:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hyph}{-\penalty\z@\hskip\z@skip }
\makeatother

9\hyph dimensional
```

this "separates" the `9-` from the following word, allowing the normal
hyphenation procedure to be activated.

**edit:**
if using `amsmath`, there's another approach: forcibly suppress the break
after the explicit hyphen, but enable ordinary hyphenation to be applied to
the following word:

```
$n$\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt)dimensional
```

this can be abbreviated in a macro as described in the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsmath`).

Answer (score 2):

This works: `9-\-di\-men\-sional`