# Warnings on running bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, errors, warnings

While running BibTeX file I got the following warnings.

> Overfull \hbox (9.74615pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--19
>   \tenrm Hatami, P., jour-nal=Australasian Jour-nal of Com-bi-na-torics, vol-ume=
>   40, num-ber=, pages=253--264, year=2008|
>
> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1--19
>
> Overfull \hbox (12.66283pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 20--91
>   \tenrm Kiyoshi and Avis, David, booktitle=North-Holland Math-e-mat-ics Stud-ies
>   , vol-ume=87, pages=13--23, year=1984,|
>   )
>   *

I copied the BibTex code from Google scholar page. 
Can anyone let me know how to fix these warnings? Thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as I can see neither of the three messages actually is an error, all of them a warnings. But of course one should also try to strive to minimise the number of warning, especially about overfull/underfull boxes. Can you show us a minimal working example that reproduces these messages. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and since were talking bibliographies [How to write a MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: You seem to be inputting `filename.bib` instead of processing it with BibTeX.

Answer (score 2):

This warning (not an error) is caused by LaTeX being unable to find a good way to format (fully-justify) your text. For example this scenario where the main text is bleeding into the right margin:

[image: text in right margin]

One way to fix this is to find the exact line that is causing the problem and rephrasing or reordering it in a way that LaTeX has enough segmented "words" on which it can introduce a linebreak.

Comment: Rephrasing or reordering does not seem like a good method to apply to bibliography entry metadata.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I had encountered this exact problem myself a couple days ago and it was caused by the title of the publication containing year, month and more information that was **also** in the rest of the metadata. Thus leading to duplicate data and a title so long that LaTeX didn't know how to properly format it. In this scenario rephrasing might be a logical solution. Sadly BibTeX citations aren't as consistently formatted as they could be, which means that making manual tweaks sometimes will yield better results.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit of a guess (not having a MWE). It seems to me that the problems of the two warnings are due to the TeX hyphenation mechanism not being able to find/knowing suitable hyphenations for the word "Australasian" and "North-Holland".  For the problem with "Australian" you can add the specific hyphenation (adding the following to the preamble of your document).

```
\hypenation={Aus-tralasian}
```

For the problem with "North-Holland" see the following question and the related answers.

[Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/adequate-hyphenation-of-words-already-containing-a-hyphen)