# Hyphenation exception syntax for LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, polyglossia

I want to hyphenate some German words. As an example, for the word `Erb-b2-Familie`, I want

- the first hyphen sign to be non-breakable
- the second hyphen sign to be breakable
- the rest of the word (`Familie`) to be hyphenated as ususal.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{
    Tyrosin"-kinase, Erb"~b2-Familie
}\\[2em]

\hyphenation{Tyrosin-kinase}    % <- this works
\hyphenation{Erb=b2=Fa-mi-lie}  % <- this does not?
\parbox{0pt}{
    Tyrosinkinase, Erb-b2-Familie
}

\end{document}
```

I cannot find a good reference for how to use the `\hyphenation{}` command, in particular what the syntax of the exception word lists is.
In [a different question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162957) I found the option to use a `=` character to denote a breakable hyphen sign, but even that does not seem to work in my example.

Comment: I can't test now but I wouldn't have expected words with digits to hyphenate at all (without changes to the lccode).

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this, is to don't define a hyphenation for this word, but instead use this special symbol `‑` in the text where you want to not break and the normal symbol `-` where a break would be ok (tested with LuaTeX). The symbol `=` seems to not have any effect, as you also said.